# Get text from text fields if there is a text

Tags: java, android

Here's my code:

```
if (e0.getText().length()==0)   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e01+n02+n03+n05);
if (e1.getText().length()==0)   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+n02+n03+n05);
if (n2.getText().length()==0)   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+e01+n03+n05);
if (n3.getText().length()==0)   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+e01+n02+n05);
if (n5.getText().length()==0)   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+e01+n02+n03);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0)       
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, n02+n03+n05);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 )                                                                                                
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e01+n03+n05);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e01+n02+n05);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e01+n02+n03);
if (e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 )    
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+n03+n05);
if (e1.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+n02+n05);
if (e1.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+n02+n03);
if (n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+e01+n05);
if (n2.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+e01+n03);
if (n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+e01+n02);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, n03+n05);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, n02+n05);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, n02+n03);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 )    
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e01+n05);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e01+n03);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e01+n02);
if (e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+n05);
if (e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+n03);
if (e1.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+n02);
if (n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e00+e01);         
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 )   
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,n05);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,n03);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,n02);         
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,e01);
if (e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0 )   
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,e00);
if (e0.getText().length()==0 && e1.getText().length()==0 && n2.getText().length()==0 && n3.getText().length()==0 && n5.getText().length()==0){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wprowadź wartości zamówienia",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       return;  
};
```

And now:
I've got 5 text fields(numbers) these are an amounts of parts I'm ordering in my application. I am puting them to email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,e01). 
How can I put also proper string that my EXTRA_TEXT wiill look for example :
"Electrode E0 -" e00 " pcs "

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: @Barmar: +1; if I had to guess, I would say the `Intent` variable suggests Android (i.e., Java).

Comment: All this repetitive coding suggests poor design. You should be using arrays for all the similar variables, and then you can use loops to implement patterns.

Comment: I'm doing this in ECLIPSE for Android

Comment: How can I use arrays?

Comment: Great help. Thank you very much for everybody. Really great.

Comment: **ALWAYS** use brackets for code blocks or you ask for troubles...